# Change file name of CarrieWave model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a Rails model like this using ImageUploader which inherit `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base` .

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader
end
```

A bug in my app caused mismatches between `images.file` column value and the actual file name in GCS, so I want to do like this:

```
Image.first.file = "fixed_file_name.jpg"
Image.save
```

But `Image#file` does not return its `file` column value, but returns `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base` instance.

How can I update the file name, JUST like `UPDATE ... SET ...` in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably like this: `User.where(id: 1).update_all(avatar: 'x.png')`

Comment: Thanks! Just `User.find(1).update(avatar: 'x.png')` works too?